# How to fill in redux-form inputs in FireFox/Edge via Webdriver automated tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selenium-webdriver, redux, automated-tests

[Webdriver.io](https://webdriver.io/) is an automated test lib.

In Chrome and Safari I'm able to use either [setValue](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/setValue.html) or [addValue](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/addValue.html) using [xpaths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) to fill in a text input and submit a form during automated tests.

However in Edge/FireFox I cannot, these commands don't work.

- [Also found this issue on Github.](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/3324)
- [developer.microsoft : setValue() command does not work](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/22429136/)

Looking around I found a work-around involving `browser.addCommand` and `browser.execute` which I've used below and it will fill in the redux-form visually. However the form doesn't detect that the form has actually been filled :( So thus the automated Submit button won't continue if it's been clicked.

### browser.execute workaround

```
browser.addCommand('setInputValue', function(element, value) {
    const webBrowser = browser.capabilities.browserName.toLowerCase();

    if (webBrowser === ‘microsoftedge’ || webBrowser === ‘firefox’) {
        browser.execute((el, val) => {           
            const regex = /\'(.*)\'/; // pulls name out of xpath
            const extractedName = el.match(regex)[1];

            document.getElementsByName(extractedName)[0].focus();
            document.getElementsByName(extractedName)[0].value = val;

        }, element, value);
    }
    else {
        $(element).setValue(value);
    }
});
```

How it's used:

```
setFirstName: value => {
    const xpath = "//input[@name='firstName']";
    browser.setInputValue(xpath, value);
    // $(xpath).setValue(value); // <- normal webdriver method which doesn't work
}
```

### Tried dispatchEvent

[From this example](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10135#issuecomment-500929024), but same problem.

```
if (webBrowser === 'microsoftedge' || webBrowser === 'firefox') {
    browser.execute((el, val) => {
        const regex = /\'(.*)\'/; // pulls name out of xpath
        const extractedName = el.match(regex)[1];

        // https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10135#issuecomment-500929024
        const input = document.getElementsByName(extractedName)[0];
        input.value = val;
        input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));

        // document.getElementsByName(extractedName)[0].focus();
        // document.getElementsByName(extractedName)[0].value = val;

    }, element, value);
}
```

Have any of you run into this issue before when using Webdriver to automate tests on FireFox or Edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out! Our configuration file was out of date, this configuration file worked:

```
const browsers = {
    chrome: [
        {
            browserName: 'Chrome',
            browserVersion: 'latest',
            platform: 'Windows 10',
            parentTunnel: 'x_admin',
            tunnelIdentifier: 'x_tunnel',
            name: 'Chrome Tests',
            chromeOptions: {
                args: ['user-agent=selenium']
            }
        }
    ],
    firefox: [
        {
            browserName: 'Firefox',
            browserVersion: 'latest',
            platformName: 'Windows 10',
            'sauce:options': {
                parentTunnel: 'x_admin',
                tunnelIdentifier: 'x_tunnel',
                name: 'Firefox Tests',
                seleniumVersion: '3.11.0',
                firefoxOptions: {
                    args: ['user-agent=selenium']
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    safari: [
        {
            browserName: 'Safari',
            browserVersion: 'latest',
            platformName: 'macOS 10.13',
            'sauce:options': {
                parentTunnel: 'x_admin',
                tunnelIdentifier: 'x_tunnel',
                name: 'Safari Tests',
                seleniumVersion: '3.11.0',
                safariOptions: {
                    args: ['user-agent=selenium']
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    explorer: [
        {
            browserName: 'Internet Explorer',
            browserVersion: 'latest',
            platform: 'Windows 10',
            parentTunnel: 'x_admin',
            tunnelIdentifier: 'x_tunnel',
            name: 'Internet Explorer Tests',
            explorerOptions: {
                args: ['user-agent=selenium']
            }
        }
    ],
    edge: [
        {
            browserName: 'MicrosoftEdge',
            browserVersion: '18.17763',
            platformName: 'Windows 10',
            'sauce:options': {
                parentTunnel: 'x_admin',
                tunnelIdentifier: 'x_tunnel',
                name: 'Microsoft Edge Tests',
                seleniumVersion: '3.141.59',
                edgeOptions: {
                    args: ['user-agent=selenium']
                }
            }
        }
    ]
};
const capabilities = {
    chrome: browsers.chrome,
    safari: browsers.safari,
    edge: browsers.edge,
    explorer: browsers.explorer,
    firefox: browsers.firefox,
    all_browsers: [].concat(
        browsers.chrome,
        browsers.safari,
        browsers.firefox,
        browsers.explorer,
        browsers.edge
    )
};

exports = module.exports = capabilities;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10135#issuecomment-314441175

You will need to trigger on change event in react or you can use the above workaround (set native value)

sample code in typescript, but it is not recommended since it doesn't simulate the actual user input.

```
browser.addCommand(
  "setNativeValue",
  function(this: any, value: string) {
    browser.execute(
      function(element, val) {
        try {
          const valueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(element, "value");
          const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(element);
          const prototypeValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, "value");

          if (valueSetter && valueSetter !== prototypeValueSetter) {
            prototypeValueSetter!.set!.call(element, val);
          } else {
            valueSetter!.set!.call(element, val);
          }
          const event = document.createEvent("Event");
          event.initEvent("input", true, true);
          element.dispatchEvent(event);
        } catch {
          element.value = val;
        }
      },
      this,
      value,
    );
  },
  true,
);
```